# Segmentation fault GCC

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, segmentation-fault, internal

I'm modifying gcc, specifically adding a new clause to OpenMP.

after compiling my test program it gives me this error:

```
"test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:10:1: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault"
```

How can i debug this?

I've searched for a while but have not found useful information...

Comment: Check your code for errors; generate some debug messages to check assumptions; build it with debug symbols and run gdb on it.

Comment: You can debug the compiler like any other program. Make sure you have debug symbols and run it with valgrind or gdb.

Comment: I found [gcc documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/segfault.html) that gives tips on how to debug it. Enabling checking and rebuilding gcc might make the debugger break (at an assert) right at a place that tells you what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good tutorial on gdb :
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/